# Allow for dragging threejs globe on mobile?

Tags: javascript, mobile, three.js, draggable

I have a globe that I created using threejs. I am using orbit controls to make it draggable. My problem is that on touch devices the dragging does not work properly. On edge you can't drag it at all and on firefox you can drag it horizontally but if you drag it vertically it will scroll down instead of dragging. How can I allow for dragging on mobile?

here is my orbitcontrols code:

```
this._controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(this._camera, this._renderer.domElement);
this._controls.rotateSpeed = .08;
this._controls.zoomSpeed = 1.0;
this._controls.enableZoom = false;
this._controls.enablePan = false;
this._controls.enableDamping = true;
this._controls.minDistance = 23.0;
this._controls.maxDistance = 70.0;
this._controls.dampingFactor = 0.1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `THREE.OrbitControl` only [listens for mouse and touch events](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/302c693b27663d4d280b156b5ebe4ed38cd062e4/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js#L890-L898) on render's DOM element, where as Edge uses [Pointer Events](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/dev-guide/dom/pointer-events/), Firefox doesn't support touch event properly at all. As for mobile devices with [Touch Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent) should work fine.

Comment: Would it work properly if I was using the trackballcontrols? Is there a controller that would do what i need?

Comment: @rjdude31 [mr. doob seems to be reluctant to add pointer events](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4015) support until it lands in all major browsers. Meantime, [this](https://github.com/Steditor/three-pointer-controls) probably can help you with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a touch event helper such as [Hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/) ? It's primary use are gestures but I successfully used Hammer to fix compatibility issues regarding also plain simple touch interaction.